# How to access a key value pair dynamically is JS/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, key-value

I have a spreadsheet element with it's cells value stored in an object like so:

`localCells = {A1: {input: 'hi', value: 'world'}, A2: {input:'how', value:'you?'}}`

It's very long like so:

`localCells = {A1: {…}, B1: {…}, C1: {…}, D1: {…}, A2: {…}, …}`

I have an array which stores the currently selected cells, like so:

`selected = ["A1", "B3"]`

When I execute a function, I want to get the value of each of the cells from the above array

I have tried this:

```js
         for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
          console.log(localCells.selected[i])
        }
```

This is my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Thank you

Comment: You are checking `selected.length` but you are using `localCells.selected[i]` huh?? It should be `localCells[selected[i]]`

Comment: Yes. I just need to get the values of the selected cells. Not all the cells obviously @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable as object key only with `[]` notation. So it should be:

```
for (let cellId of selected) {
    console.log(localCells[cellId])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```js
let localCells = {A1: {input: 'hi', value: 'world'}, A2: {input:'how', value:'you?'}};
let selected = ["A1", "B3"];
for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    if (localCells[selected[i]])
        console.log(localCells[selected[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up how dot and bracket notation works. When you are doing `localCells.selected[i]` For that line of code to work, your object would be:

```
localCells = {
  selected: [0,1,2,3]
}
```

It is not saying `localCells.a1` as you think it is.

You can not use dot notation here, you need to use brackets. Breaking it up to be more readable

```
var key = selected[i]
var cell = localCells[key];
console.log(cell);
```

In one line

```
var cell = localCells[selected[i]];
```

example running:

```js
var localCells = {
  A1: {
    input: 'hi',
    value: 'world'
  },
  B3: {
    input: 'how',
    value: 'you?'
  }
}
var selected = ["A1", "B3"]

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
  var key = selected[i];
  var cell = localCells[key];
  console.log(cell);

  var cell2 = localCells[selected[i]];
  console.log(cell2);
}

//using forEach
selected.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(localCells[key]);
});

const selectedObjects = selected.map(function(key) {
  return localCells[key];
});
console.log(selectedObjects);
```